# Inverse of snprintf

Tags: c++, c

Is there any function in C or C++ to perform the inverse of an snprintf, such that

```
 char buffer[256]
 snprintf( buffer, 256, "Number:%i", 10);

 // Buffer now contains "Number:10"

 int i;
 inverse_snprintf(buffer,"Number:%i", &i);

 // i now contains 10
```

I can write a function that meets this requirement myself, but is there already one within the standard libraries?

Comment: [`sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) perhaps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there is [`sscanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).  It returns the number of tokens successfully matched to the input, so you can check the return value to see how far it made it into the input string.

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "Number:%i", &i) == 1) {
    /* The number was successfully parsed */
}
```

Comment: Of course, one needs to make sure the input to `sscanf` is properly null-terminated first.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone Well... yes. That is true of nearly every function accepting a C string.

Comment: The C++ standard library switched over from using `fscanf` family (C++03) to using e.g. `strtoll` (C++11) in order to avoid certain UB issues. I'd recommend for the OP to use [`strol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) instead of `sscanf`.

Comment: Alf: `strtol` and friends don't parse the prompt string. The resulting code wouldn't be an "inverse" of `snprintf`.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone: That's a *very dangerous* view/idea to have. One cannot in general pass a `sprintf` format string to `sscanf`. Consider e.g. `sprintf` `"double %f"` versus `sscanf` `"float %f"`: thinking the specifier means the same type in both cases leads to UB.

Comment: Recommend `%d` instead of `"%i"`.  With `...printf("%i"` or `...printf("%d"` will always print a decimal number and `sscanf("%d"` will always scan as  a decimal.  `sscanf("%i"` may interpret the string as octal or hexadecimal like "077".

Comment: The return value of `sccanf()` (0, 1, or EOF) only weakly allows code to know how far it made it into the input string.  `strtol()` indicates the exact position scanning stopped - but then additional code would be need to skip the "Number:".

Comment: @Alf: "One cannot in general..." -- No, but they can in limited cases. There is a subset of format components which are reversible. So long as they stick to that, they're okay. And the odd cases could be handled with macros or similar, or just left unsupported, if they're even needed. Either way, it's far less work and far less likely to fail than what would be effectively a complete rewrite of `sscanf`. Finally, if a truly robust parser is needed, they should use `boost.spirit`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `sscanf()`, if you are only going to scan numbers, you can safely scan numeric values using the `strto*()` functions: `strtol()`, `strtoll()`, `strtoul()`, `strtoull()`, `strtof()`, `strtod()`, `strtold()`. You can also use `atoi()`, `atol()` and `atoll()`, but note that these functions return `0` if the string is not an integer that can be converted.