# Is passing a float to printf undefined behavior?

Tags: c, printf

The C99 standard talks about **double**s in the specification for `fprintf` (which subsequently applies to `printf`). It says "a `double` argument representing a floating-point number is converted..." Then in paragraph 9, it says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.
>   If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   specification, the behavior is undefined.

So I would expect the following to be undefined behavior but my compiler doesn't warn about it.

```
double d = 2.0;
float f = 2.0f;
printf("%f", d);
printf("%f", f); // here
```

On the other hand, the specification for `fscanf` says "floating point number" instead of double. Is it undefined behavior like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487775/inverse-of-snprintf/27487797#comment43408227_27487797) claims?

Comment: Floats in C are automatically promoted to `double`, which is why the spec talks about doubles, but not about `float`

Comment: I would think there is a "conversion specification" for the type conversion from `float` to `double`, hence making `printf` expect a `double` but being passed a `float` fine, as `float can be implicitly converted to `double`.

Comment: The [user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27487775/inverse-of-snprintf/27487797#comment43408227_27487797) claim about UB relates to `scanf()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ variadic functions and default promotions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844360/c-c-variadic-functions-and-default-promotions)

Comment: @chux - Since `scanf` is a pointer, it doesn't promote a pointer to a `float` to a pointer to a `double`.

Comment: @icemanind `scanf()` is not a pointer, but a function. And why comment about the obvious?

Comment: @chux - scanf() is a function that expects a pointer as one of its parameters. And it isn't obvious to the OP apparently, because he asked the question as to why.

Comment: @icemanind Then address the comment to the OP, not to me.

Comment: this line: printf("%f", d); is the actual problem as a double value would need to be downgraded to float for a printf to be always successful.  That is not how things work, variables are promoted, not downgraded.  writing: printf("%lf",d); would be correct.  there is nothing wrong with the second call to printf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559198/why-does-printf-implicit-loat-to-int-conversion-not-work , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303673/why-cast-is-needed-in-printf

Comment: @Deduplicator You should focus more on making every body understand the answer . Rather than just going everywhere and finding duplicate. Even the co-founder of stackoverflow said duplicates are good . It increase site traffic. Also this is not really a duplicate.

Comment: @SurajJain He only said *some duplication is good*. This duplication though plainly isn't. The answer on the dupe, though short, might be more than the absolute minimum, but that doesn't mean it isn't a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passing a `float` to `printf` is not undefined behavior--it's simply an impossibility. The `float` will be promoted to `double` before `printf` receives it.

`scanf` is different because what you're (at least normally) passing to `scanf` are *pointers* rather than the data objects themselves. Since you're passing a pointer to the original data, with `scanf` you need to distinguish between a `float` and a `double`.

Answer (score 4):

`float` in vararg functions are always promoted to `double`.

`scanf` deals with pointers.